# How to find link using selenium when "linktext" is a div?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium-webdriver

```html
<a href="/r/androidapps/comments/13olal1/what_happens_to_photos_resized_in_samsung_builtin/">
  <div class="_1AKeAGcglmBjK1SUUXNFti _1-SZ3VwLjbFwTzaZvU8FBX _1FT0e6kh1BBb_oALAMW_l7 _1yBpz1MEPxxYTxjlEilGtB" data-testid="post-title" style="--posttitletextcolor:#222222">
    <h3 class="_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m">what happens to photos resized in Samsung built-in gallery app</h3>   </div>
</a>
```

I want "/r/androidapps/comments/13olal1/what_happens_to_photos_resized_in_samsung_builtin/" in the "a" tag. How do I use selenium to get the url as a string?
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, **WHAT GOES HERE?**)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find that information using:

```
element_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="post-title"]/ancestor::a').get_attribute('href')
```

Selenium documentation can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/).

Answer (score 0):

The code using `LINK_TEXT` should be:

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "what happens to photos resized in Samsung built-in gallery app")
```

If you want to print the `href` attribute and check, try the below code:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "what happens to photos resized in Samsung built-in gallery app")
print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

It should print the below in the console:

```
/r/androidapps/comments/13olal1/what_happens_to_photos_resized_in_samsung_builtin/
```